# Re sample/down sample csv from 501 to 101 nodes in Matlab

Tags: matlab, csv, resampling

I have ground reaction force csv files which are 501x11 / 11x501 double

> > Female_GRF = csvread('Female_Fz.csv');
> > Male_GRF = csvread('Male_Fz.csv');

> > Female_GRF = Female_GRF';
> > Male_GRF = Male_GRF';

Please can anyone direct me how I can resample or downsample these from 501 nodes to 101x11 / 11x101?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO! You're asking us to write code for you but haven't showed any effort on your behalf, which is off-topic. Instead, show us your attempt to solve the problem, and ask a specific question about the problem you're having. In addition it sounds like you're asking for recommendations for code or a tutorial, which is again off topic. See "[ask]" and its linked pages.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab has a builtin downsampling method:

`>> Female_GRF = downsample(Female_GRF,5);`

replaces `Female_GRF` with the downsampled version.

On the other hand, if by "downsample", you mean keep every 5th entry, then that's easier: the command

`>> Female_GRF = Female_GRF(1:5:end);`

replaces the variable `Female_GRF` with a "downsampled" version.